# Can't deploy to Vercel - error - Route does not match the required types of a Next.js Route

Tags: vercel, next.js13

Newbie question:

Next.js 13 app - trying to deploy to Vercel

Type error: Route "app/api/auth/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.
"getAuth" is not a valid Route export field.

Type error: Route does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.

this page is also sending a httpOnly cookie - could that be part of the problem?

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
export async function POST(req, res) {
  const raw = await req.json();
  const body = raw.request;

  const nowserver = body.server;
  const nowfile = body.file;

  let nowsecretpass = 'xxx';
  const nowauth = `xxx`;
  const nowurl = `xxx`;

  let config = {
    method: 'post',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: nowurl,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: nowauth,
    },
  };

  const data = await getAuth (config);
  const token = data.response.token;
  const response = NextResponse.json(data, { status: 200 })

  response.cookies.set({
    name: 'mytoken',
    value: token,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "strict",
    maxAge: 60 * 60,
    path: "/",
  })

  return response
}
export async function getAuth (config) {
  const axios = require ('axios');
  const response = await axios.request (config);
  return response.data;
}
```

all my other pages seemed to deploy ok - (written in a similar fashion) - just this one has this error... Could it be the httpOnly cookie ? Is there some way to fix this

UPDATE: I think I may have found the issue: there are 2 exports on the page - the 2nd is not needed so when I changed it to just async function getAuth (no export word) - then it seems to now be working ok - does this seem like it was the issue?